# Get text between two rounded brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I retrieve the word `my` from between the two rounded brackets in the following sentence using a regex in JavaScript?

> "This is (my) simple text"

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```js
console.log(
  "This is (my) simple text".match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]
);
```

`\(` being opening brace, `(` — start of subexpression, `[^)]+` — anything but closing parenthesis one or more times (you may want to replace `+` with `*`), `)` — end of subexpression, `\)` — closing brace. The `match()` returns an array `["(my)","my"]` from which the second element is extracted.

Comment: You can use `.+?` instead of `[^)]+` too.

Comment: Yes, there're quite a few ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: +1 Nice, worked like a charm. I would like to add you to add this http://tinyurl.com/mog7lr3 in your for a visual explanation.  Thank you

Comment: Use `.match(/\{(.+?)\}/g)` if there are multiple results

Comment: i get .match(...) is null when try to apply this

Comment: "this" being which? And what do you apply it to?

Comment: @Michael.  I too get null when I apply "this".  This= the regex in the Answer given.  If I leave the [1] off, I get the returned text but with the () around it.  If I add the [1] at the end, it returns null.  If I use .+? it returns as expected for me,..sometimes.  I am trying to pull characters from in between ().  So when applied to USD - United States Dollar ($) it will return $.  But when I try to do the same for AED - UAE Dirham (د.إ)  it only returns د   this is beyond frustrating.  I just want to pull these characters from inside (), it shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @general, I'm not sure how do you get there, it sounds like your `match` returns a single string instead of array, which is not what `match` is supposed to do. I can't seem to reproduce it, what's the exact isolated code you're running? I can evaluate `'AED - UAE Dirham (د.إ)'.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1]` and get the expected result?

Answer (score 21):

```
var txt = "This is (my) simple text";
re = /\((.*)\)/;
console.log(txt.match(re)[1]);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TSuXq/)**

Comment: If we change the txt to txt = 'This is (my) (simple) text' it is giving 'my) (simple' as output. Ho can we get only my. How can we get content within matching parenthesis only?

Comment: @smita change (.*) to (.*?) for non-greedy matching

Answer (score 17):

You may also try a non-regex method (of course if there are multiple such brackets, it will eventually need looping, or regex)

```
init = txt.indexOf('(');
fin = txt.indexOf(')');
console.log(txt.substr(init+1,fin-init-1))
```

Comment: Easier to use `substring`: `txt.substring(init + 1, fin)`

Comment: That said, yes, going non-regex is an option that shouldn't be underestimated.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Got your point, but even your regex method will not give the correct result if the string is somewhat like **A ( is meant to start and then finish it off, like (my).**

Comment: Exactly. Speed may not be an issue here, but in general regex matches are time-consuming.

Comment: @Cupidvogel, in this case the question is what exactly the OP wants in this case. It's not clear to me whether the result that my regex will give is incorrect. You may wish to change it to `[^()]` of course, but whether that's correct is also not clear.
And yes, not only performance, but it's just about the popular tendency to do *everything* with regex that would make me upvote your answer if you added some checks ;-)

Comment: I can't think of any check. I could check whether `fin >= init`, but that won't solve the case, there may be more than two **)**, but we can never know which of the ones following the **(** is meant to end the opening parentheses.

Comment: Well, it largely depends on the original intension of course, but using `fin < init` doesn't sound like a right thing to do. You can (a) search for closing paren starting at opening, (b) find the last closing paren, (c) whatever one may come up with ;-)

Comment: Looks like heck of a work. No wonder people resort to regexes!

Answer (score 9):

For anyone looking to return multiple texts in multiple brackets

```
var testString = "(Charles) de (Gaulle), (Paris) [CDG]"
var reBrackets = /\((.*?)\)/g;
var listOfText = [];
var found;
while(found = reBrackets.exec(testString)) {
  listOfText.push(found[1]);
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this to get text between closest `(` and `)`:

```js
const string = "This is (my) (simple (text)"
console.log( string.match(/\(([^()]*)\)/)[1] )
console.log( string.match(/\(([^()]*)\)/g).map(function($0) { return $0.substring(1,$0.length-1) }) )
```

**Results**: `my` and `["my","text"]`.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

Comment: Nice one liner ill be using this

Answer (score 2):

to get fields from string formula.

```
var txt = "{{abctext/lsi)}} = {{abctext/lsi}} + {{adddddd}} / {{ttttttt}}";
re = /\{{(.*?)\}}/g;
console.log(txt.match(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

to return multiple items within rounded brackets

```
 var res2=str.split(/(|)/);

  var items=res2.filter((ele,i)=>{
  if(i%2!==0) {
  return ele;
  }
});
```