# REGEX - after bracket get data until end bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following:

```
SOME TEXT (BI1) SOME MORE TEXT (BI17) SOME FINAL TEXT (BI1234)
```

**Question**

*I am trying to make a regex to get just the information between the curly brackets*, for example the end string would look like:

```
BI1 BI17 BI1234
```

I have found this example on stackoverflow which will get the first value BI1, but will ignore the rest after.
[Get text between two rounded brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059284/get-text-between-two-rounded-brackets)

this is the REGEX I created from the above link: `/\(([^)]+)\)/g` but it includes the brackets, I want to remove these.

[image]

I am using this website to attempt to solve this query which has a testing window to see if the regex entered works:
http://www.regexr.com

**Additional Information**

- there can be any amount of numbers also, which is why I have given 3 different examples.
- this is a continous string, not on seperate lines

thanks for any help on this matter.

Comment: Does it mean you need to remove all text but that inside the parentheses?

Comment: yes i would like to remove all of the text, apart from what is inside the curly brackets. I do not want the curly brackets included either.

Comment: edited question above to include the closest example I have got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't possible using *just* regexes, you can do it with `string#split` and the following regex:

```
\).*?\(|^.*?\(|\).*?$
```

Yielding code that looks a bit like this:

```
function getBracketed(str) {
    return str.split(/\).*?\(|^.*?\(|\).*?$/).filter(Boolean);
}
```

(You need to filter out the empty strings that'll appear at the beginning and end if you do it this way - hence the extra operation).

- [Regex demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e6aQyB/2)
- [Code demo on Repl.it](https://repl.it/EBjy/0)

Comment: That works brilliant except the first string is still present: SOME TEXT

Comment: @Crezzer7: This regex is meant to match everything ***but*** your target text, to split the string by it. regexr also shows the correct results - all of the text except the stuff in the brackets is highlighted, meaning it's working correctly. Try running the demo I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep all inside parentheses and remove everything else, you might use

```js
var str = "SOME TEXT (BI1) SOME MORE TEXT (BI17) SOME FINAL TEXT (BI1234)";
var result = str.replace(/.*?\(([^()]*)\)/g, " $1").trim();
console.log(result);
```

If you need to get only the `BI`+digits pattern inside parentheses, use

```
/.*?\((BI\d+)\)/g
```

**Details**:

- `.*?` - match any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols
- `\(` -  match a `(`
- `(BI\d+)` - Group 1 capturing `BI` + 1 or more digits (`\d+`) (or `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`)
- `\)` - a closing `)`.

To get all the values as array (say, for later joining), use

```js
var str = "SOME TEXT (BI1) SOME MORE TEXT (BI17) SOME FINAL TEXT (BI1234)";
var re = /\((BI\d+)\)/g;
var res =str.match(re).map(function(s) {return s.substring(1, s.length-1);})
console.log(res);
console.log(res.join(" "));
```